# how to parse html text file in terminal?

Tags: html, linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I have a text file that even after removing all the html tags still contains some html codes of apostrophes and other punctuations example :

```
  It&#039;s  // It's
```

my question is how to change all of them?

and I'm using a bash script under linux  to get the html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Python:

```
$ echo 'It&#039;s' | python -c 'import xmllib,sys; print(xmllib.XMLParser().translate_references(sys.stdin.read()))'
It's
```

#### Using Perl:

```
$ echo 'It&#039;s' | perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_);'
It's
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you got `lynx` use it as:

```
lynx -stdin -dump < file.html
```

The above will remove the HTML tags too, for example from this `file.html`

```
<i>It&#039;s</i>
&lt;<b>&amp;</b>&#62;
```

prints

```
   It's <&>
```